# ReactJS not rendering php codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, html, reactjs, material-ui

I am currently using material-ui library which makes use of reactjs and google material design which can be found here http://www.material-ui.com/#/  I have tried following one of their examples on their github page, which did not work.  I have now tried doing a simple test to see if it would render by following this post [React JS not rendering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32996706/react-js-not-rendering). However to my luck nothing has changed and it would not render.

Here is my react code:

```
import React from 'libraries/react';
import RaisedButton from 'libraries/material-ui/lib/raised-button';
import ReactDOM from 'libraries/react-dom';

var HelloMessage = React.createClass({
    render: function () {
        return <h1>Hello {this.props.message}! </h1>;
    }
});

React.render(HelloMessage, message="World" , document.getElementById('body'));
```

and here is my HTML:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
?><!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Welcome to CodeIgniter</title>

    <style type="text/css">

        ::selection { background-color: #E13300; color: white; }
        ::-moz-selection { background-color: #E13300; color: white; }

        body {
            background-color: #fff;
            margin: 40px;
            font: 13px/20px normal Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
            color: #4F5155;
        }

        a {
            color: #003399;
            background-color: transparent;
            font-weight: normal;
        }

        h1 {
            color: #444;
            background-color: transparent;
            border-bottom: 1px solid #D0D0D0;
            font-size: 19px;
            font-weight: normal;
            margin: 0 0 14px 0;
            padding: 14px 15px 10px 15px;
        }

        code {
            font-family: Consolas, Monaco, Courier New, Courier, monospace;
            font-size: 12px;
            background-color: #f9f9f9;
            border: 1px solid #D0D0D0;
            color: #002166;
            display: block;
            margin: 14px 0 14px 0;
            padding: 12px 10px 12px 10px;
        }

        #body {
            margin: 0 15px 0 15px;
        }

        p.footer {
            text-align: right;
            font-size: 11px;
            border-top: 1px solid #D0D0D0;
            line-height: 32px;
            padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
            margin: 20px 0 0 0;
        }

        #container {
            margin: 10px;
            border: 1px solid #D0D0D0;
            box-shadow: 0 0 8px #D0D0D0;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="container">
    <h1>Welcome to CodeIgniter!</h1>

    <div id="body">

    </div>

    <p class="footer">Page rendered in <strong>{elapsed_time}</strong> seconds. <?php echo  (ENVIRONMENT === 'development') ?  'CodeIgniter Version <strong>' . CI_VERSION . '</strong>' : '' ?></p>
</div>
</body>
<script type="text/jsx" src="application/scripts/reactTest.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: try `ReactDOM.render(<HelloMessage message="World" />, document.getElementById('body'))`

Comment: @azium I have tried that, however it does render anything

Comment: And no errors in the browser console?

Comment: @azium I am using firebug and there doesn't seem to be any, saying that I can't seem to find the script on the sources tab in google chrome nor the script tab on firebug

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
React.render(<HelloMessage message="World"/>, document.body);
```

Comment: and with ReactDOM.render instead of React.render ?

Comment: keep cool sebastian, I honestly thought it was the solution of his problem. I'm also getting into AngularJS and I had a similar problem. React.render did the trick for me, unfortunately that's not the case for Johnathon64

Comment: @rmpt I was wondering could it be the case that I actually need to run it through webpack and include it in my html as a script tag?

Comment: I'm not sure if I got your question, but you need to include 
https://fb.me/react-0.14.0.min.js
in your html page in order to use ReactJS.